# I can't play video in angular

Tags: angular, video

I am working on a project in angular, I have component witch should play video from js file.

This is my html

```
 <video width="276" height="540" class="video-element" id="video-element" >
  <source [src]="videoFile" type="video/mp4">
  <source [src]="videoFile" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

This is my js file

```
 const playVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('video-element') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
 playVideo[0].classList.add('show'); // play video
 playVideo[0].play(); // I get error
```

And I get error : Property 'play' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)

when I try play Video from js file.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the property `play` does not exist on a plain `HTMLElement`, but it does exist on a [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play).

```
(playVideo[0] as HTMLMediaElement).play(); // should not throw a compiler error
```

Of course, if `playVideo[0]` is not actually a `HTMLMediaElement`, this will still fail.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the video element exists in DOM by the time you call play. Since you are using angular please use viewChild instead of document.

If you are testing in safari use a different browser and check how that behavior changes in safari.